# Is avatar Korra bisexual?

Tags: avatar

[image: Korra and Asami maybe being bisexual]

They were closer than they should have been and in the final scenes, it wasn't clear if they were just close friends or romantic interests.

A little google search and this is what happens:

[image: "is korra..."]

There are sources that said the creators confirmed it, but I couldn't find these sources.

Comment: Asked and answered on Scifi&Fantasy:SE; [Are Korra and Asami a couple?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81378/are-korra-and-asami-a-couple)

Comment: @Maroon I've opened a new meta discussion [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2527/7579) if you'd like to participate. Looking at the review history of the question you linked (thanks for setting me straight on that, by the way), it seems like five people voted to close and then five completely different people voted to reopen. All ten of these people are respected, high-rep users. That suggests there's a pretty deep gulf in the community around this issue.

Comment: I have [moved a number of comments about whether or not this question should be on topic to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27325/discussion-on-question-by-esq-is-avatar-korra-bisexual).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

According to **[Michael Dante Dimartino's Tumblr](http://michaeldantedimartino.tumblr.com/post/105916326500/korrasami-confirmed-now-that-korra-and-asamis)** (who's one of the main creators of the series), it was confirmed that Korra + Asami is a thing.

> Our intention with the last scene was to make it as clear as possible that yes, Korra and Asami have romantic feelings for each other. The moment where they enter the spirit portal symbolizes their evolution from being friends to being a couple.